# Can't inject EncryptedObject

Tags: bugs, evaluation, hold, security, cryptography

**Bug present from 10.0 to 10.3.1 and fixed in 10.4.0**

!!

---

Here are minimal examples:

```
encryptedObj = Encrypt["pass", "TestCase"];

Decrypt["pass", encryptedObj] (*returns correct "TestCase"*)



With[{x = encryptedObj}, Button["Try with", Decrypt["pass", x]]]

Button["Try with", Decrypt["pass", #]] &@encryptedObj
```

Clicking each button generates an error:
[image]

`"data length"` displayed in message for `encryptedObject` seems to be related to the problem because correct one is `16 bytes`.

I have no idea... I tried many things e.g. `Normal`/different forms of expression/writing to different links. With no luck.

---

As Michael Hale has pointed out `Module` will work but I need something persisting through sessions, like:

```
DynamicModule[{
  x = encryptedObj
  },

 Button["Try with", Decrypt["pass", x]]
 ]
```

which is not working either.

---

So yes, that's great an encryption is there, but what's the point if I can't distribute encrypted objects -.-

Comment: If you copy the `EncryptedObject` from the box form (Show Expression) or from the `FullForm` and execute it, you get your error, invalid `EncryptedObject`.  (I have no fix for that.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the problem might be related to a bug in `FullForm` when applied to a `ByteArray` object:

```
ByteArray["aV+jpGtfd3BHhoSvOthJpQ=="] // FullForm
(* List[105,95,163,164,107,95,119,112,71,134,132,175,58,216,73,165] *)
```

The full form has lost information regarding the structure of the `ByteArray`.  The box-form of the button is using this list form but the `EncryptedObject` operations only work with byte arrays, not lists.

**Analysis**

First, let's consider the `BoxForm` of the generated button:

```
With[{x = encryptedObj}
, MakeBoxes[Button["Try with", Decrypt["pass", x]]] // InputForm
]

(*
ButtonBox["\"Try with\"", RuleDelayed[ButtonFunction, 
   Decrypt["pass", EncryptedObject[Association[Rule["Data", 
       List[105, 95, 163, 164, 107, 95, 119, 112, 71, 134, 132, 175, 58, 
        216, 73, 165]], Rule["InitializationVector", 
       List[215, 104, 218, 122, 197, 88, 212, 206, 35, 98, 253, 85, 102, 27, 
        229, 8]], Rule["OriginalForm", String]]]]], 
  Rule[Appearance, Automatic], Rule[Evaluator, Automatic], 
  Rule[Method, "Preemptive"]]
*)
```

Take particular note of the value of the `"Data"` property of the `EncryptedObject` above.  It is a simple list.  Contrast this to the value of that property when we retrieve it directly:

```
encryptedObj["Data"]
```

[image: _ByteArray screenshot]

It is a `ByteArray`, not a list.  The box-form of the button has been corrupted somehow.  The box form is not using the `InputForm` of the byte array, which looks like this:

```
encryptedObj["Data"] // InputForm
(* ByteArray["aV+jpGtfd3BHhoSvOthJpQ=="] *)
```

Rather, it appears to be using the `FullForm`:

```
encryptedObj["Data"] // FullForm
(* List[105,95,163,164,107,95,119,112,71,134,132,175,58,216,73,165] *)
```

I suggest that it is a bug for the `FullForm` of a `ByteArray` to be a list instead of preserving its structure.  Alternatively, the code that generates the box-form of a `Button` should be using `InputForm` instead of `FullForm`.  Then again, if lists and byte arrays are supposed to be interchangeable, then perhaps the operations on `EncryptedObject` should not fail when passed lists.   Any way you slice it, the behaviour appears to be due to a bug.

**Work-around**

As suggested by @SimonWoods in a comment, a work-around is to explicitly fix the encrypted object's representation by converting the lists back into byte arrays:

```
fix[x_] := x /. l_List :> ByteArray[l]

With[{x = encryptedObj}
, Button["Try with", Print @ Decrypt["pass", fix[x]]]
]
```

Comment: I was about to post something similar. A workaround is to convert the lists back to byte arrays `x /. l_List :> ByteArray[l]`

Comment: I added a workaround section, with thanks to @SimonWoods.

Answer (score 10):

OK, now I have another suggestion:

```
With[{x = ToString[encryptedObj, InputForm]},
 Print[x];
 Button["Try with", foo = Decrypt["pass", ToExpression[x]]]]
```

The button generates no error and `foo` is set to `"TestCase"`.

Comment: @Kuba Maybe the new suggestion works?  (Still seems worth reporting your problem.)  -- Sorry about the `Print[x]`, if it's annoying.  I meant to delete it.

Comment: Funny but works :) Thanks. Yes, will report this.

Answer (score 7):

I think you've found a bug. It seems to me that the Encrypt/Decrypt functionality introduced in 10.1 needs more work. But, I have found that the following work around may help. If you explicitly pass the `EncryptedObject` properties into an `EncryptedObject` via its `Association` parameter, they will be correctly interpreted with no errors. Try this:

```
encryptedObj = Encrypt["pass", "TestCase"];

Dynamic[data]
DynamicModule[{}, 
  Button["Try with", data = Decrypt["pass", 
    EncryptedObject[<|"Data" -> encryptedObj["Data"], 
      "InitializationVector" -> encryptedObj["InitializationVector"], 
      "OriginalForm" -> encryptedObj["OriginalForm"]|>]]]
]
```

The result is:

[image: Decrypt output]