# How to zip a folder?

Tags: files-and-directories, compression

This straightforward approach doesn't seem to work:

```
In[42]:= cmd = StringSplit@"zip -r ~/data.zip ~/test/*"
In[43]:= RunProcess@cmd
```

[image]

Related: [How can I encrypt/decrypt a directory?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104172/how-can-i-encrypt-decrypt-a-directory)

Comment: Try the less straightforward approach that doesn't assume `zip` will do wildcard expansion, which is the job of the shell... this is nothing to do with *Mathematica*, it seems to me.

Comment: Are you aware of `CreateArchive`?

Comment: But this command works in the terminal @OleksandrR.

Comment: @Pickett Forgot that one, yup that solves it. But it would be nice to understand why this command that works in the shell won't work when invoked with RunProcess. If you post this as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @M.R. what do you expect? The purpose of "the terminal" is to run a shell. Try `exec`ing `zip` directly from C and see if it works--I bet it won't.

Comment: Sure, but isn't one purpose of RunProcess to enable you to run a shell process and interact with it?

Comment: Ah we are getting to the heart of the issue -> I don't think it replaces a shell, but the shell is a process that RunProcess and friends were made to work with. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @M.R. you have nowhere attempted to run a shell. You just call `zip` directly. I am sure it would work if you used the/a shell to evaluate this command line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34513/discussion-between-m-r-and-oleksandr-r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *Mathematica* 8.0 we are in luck and there is a command called `CreateArchive` that can do this for us. Documentation: [`CreateArchive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CreateArchive.html).